# Prevent JQuery Mobile swipe event over specific element

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery, swipe, preventdefault

I am using jquery mobile and I need to prevent swipe event over specific element. Need of doing this is because I am using slider and I don't want the swipe event to be invoked resp. I want it to be prevented when user is manipulating with slider. I was not able to too find any solution so I am asking for help here.

This is my javascript code:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#demo-page", function() {
  $( document ).on( "swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function( e ) {

  // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
  // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
  // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).

   if ( $.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open" ) {
     if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
        $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
           $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use both, `stopPropagation();` and `preventDefault();`.

As for the `.selector`, it can be a *tag* and *#ID* or *.class*, e.g. `[data-role=page]#PageID` , `div.ui-content`...etc

```
$(document).on('swipeleft swiperight', '.selector', function(event) {
 event.stopPropagation();
 event.preventDefault();
});
```

- Reference: [stopPropagation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)
- Reference: [preventDefault();](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)
- [Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/6APh7/)

Comment: Well in my case, this prevents the slider to move but not the page transition... Is it possible to achieve the same with .on('swipe',':not(.ui-slider)',transition) ?

Comment: @IazertyuiopI you can use `:not()` selector of course.

Comment: for example, selector = `"swipeleft", ".foo:not(.ui-slider)", function`. @IazertyuiopI